# Prove that $\frac13+\frac23\times\frac15+\dots+\frac23\times\frac45\times\dots\times\frac{2n}{2n+1}\times\frac1{2n+3}<1$

Tags: inequality

How do we prove that :
$$\frac13+\frac23\times\frac15+\dots+\frac23\times\frac45\times\dots\times\frac{2n}{2n+1}\times\frac1{2n+3}<1$$

Let :
$$\text{U}_n=\frac1{2n+3}\prod_{k=1}^{n}\frac{2k}{2k+1}$$
And we know that:
$$1-\sum_{k=0}^{n}\text{U}_k=(2n+5)\text{U}_{n+1}$$

Comment: You essentially have the answer. Since you deduced $1 - \sum_{k = 0}^n U_k = (2n + 5)U_{n + 1}$, and it's clear that $U_n > 0$ since $k > 0$, then $(2n + 5)U_N > 0$. Hence, $1 - \sum_{k = 0}^n U_K > 0$ and a simple rearrangement will give you the desired inequality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You even do not need to use $$1-\sum_{k=0}^{n}\text{U}_k=(2n+5)\text{U}_{n+1}$$
since
$$\text{U}_n=\frac1{2n+3}\prod_{k=1}^{n}\frac{2k}{2k+1}=\frac{\sqrt{\pi } \,\,\Gamma (n+1)}{2 (2 n+3)\, \Gamma
   \left(n+\frac{3}{2}\right)}$$ and the summation telescopes

$$\sum_{k=0}^{n}\text{U}_k=1-\frac{\sqrt{\pi }\,\, \Gamma (n+2)}{2\, \Gamma\left(n+\frac{5}{2}\right)}$$

$$1-\sum_{k=0}^{n}\text{U}_k=\frac{\sqrt{\pi }\,\, \Gamma (n+2)}{2\, \Gamma\left(n+\frac{5}{2}\right)}\approx \sqrt{ \frac{\pi }{4 n}}$$

Answer (score 2):

Essentially the same solution but having the telescoping nature of the sum more apparent.

Let further define $V_n=\prod_{k=1}^{n}\frac{2k}{2k+1}$ (so that $U_n=\frac{V_n}{2n+3}$). Now notice $\frac{1}{2n+3}=1-\frac{2n+2}{2n+3}$ and so $U_n=V_n-V_{n+1}$. Thus the resulting sum telescopes to $\sum_{k=0}^nU_k=1-V_{n+1}$. Since it's clear that $V_n >0$ the result follows.

Answer (score 1):

Let:
$$\text{U}_n＝\frac {1}{2n＋3}\prod_{k＝1}^{n}\frac {2k}{2k＋1}$$

$$S_n=\frac {1}{3}+\frac {2}{3}×\frac {1}{5}＋^{...}＋\frac {2}{3}×\frac {4}{5}×^{...}×\frac {2n}{2n＋1}×\frac {1}{2n＋3}=\sum_{k＝0}^{n}\text{U}_k$$
We have :
$$\\~\\\\~\\1-\sum_{k＝0}^{n}\text{U}_k＝(2n＋5)\text{U}_{n＋1}>0\\~\\\implies\;1-\sum_{k＝0}^{n}\text{U}_k>0\\~\\\implies1>\sum_{k＝0}^{n}\text{U}_k\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;$$